# How do I modify bits of float/double without undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I want to set/clear bits of a float and double in C++ and print out the result. I'm positive `long long bits = *(long long*)&doubleVar;` invokes undefined behavior. I'm not sure if putting it in a union is correct either. How do I get/set bits of a float and double in C++ without causing undefined behavior?

Comment: `char* pChar = reinterpret_cast< char* >(&doubleVar);` But read details about using `reinterpret_cast` and this construct.

Comment: @P0W I think I heard it's only allowed to convert a base type to it's parent and convert an int to pointer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid undefined behavior you need to use `memcpy()`  A simple way to do this is using the proposed template `std::bit_cast<to_type>(from_type from)`

You can get the template that wraps this operation (it's only proposed) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast and is simple to use:

```
double pun_me=3.0;
std::uint64_t ui64=my_namespace::bit_cast<uint64_t>(pun_me);
```

It's a good idea to put it in a separate namespace so you don't get conflicts when/if it comes out in C++20. You can then modify whatever you wish and convert it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unsigned char *` for that, that's the simplest yet standard conformant way, if you need to modify some of the bits of an existing `float`/`double`. See:

```
float a = 1.0f;
unsigned char *x = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&a);
x[3] ^= 0x80; // let's change sign of a (assuming IEEE-754, and little-endian, 8-bit chars)
```

Doing this with `memcpy` or `bit_cast` is more complex.